# DB2 and user account control

Tags: ant, db2, uac

I've googled for the answer for some time, but I didn't find it.

I work with IBM DB2 and I have a set of sql-scripts. These scripts contains some test data, and I need this data to be loaded into my database. To load it, I need to call DB2CW.BAT, because I can't load it just using cmd. I need to load test data automatically, for this I have build.xml file which contains:

```
<target name="target-name">
    <exec dir=".." executable="cmd.exe" failonerror="true">
      <arg line="/c DB2CMDADMIN.exe DB2CW.BAT data.cmd source dbname user pass"/>
    </exec>
  </target>
```

There:

- data.cmd - script that just loads test data into db
- source - where sql-scripts with data are located

So, what's going wrong? When I run this ant-target, I catch UAC window (user account control). It asks me what to do - allow access or not for IBM DB2 to do smth. It's not a problem to just click 'Yes', but I need this data to be loaded automatically. I do not monitor the process, I just need a result. That's a problem.

I've solved it just by switching UAC off, but this solution is unacceptable for the customer. Any ideas of how to avoid this problem?

I use Windows 7 Enterprise.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Run as Administrator?

Comment: So, I've tried to change my target as follows: <arg line="runas /user:Administrator DB2CMDADMIN.exe DB2CW.BAT data.cmd source dbname user pass/>. But it didn't help